# bootstrap navbar list dropdown extends far too wide

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar dropdown with the 'bell' icon that will hopefully show some notifications. 
When for example, I add more text lines to any list item, the sentence extends horizontally and does not break on a new line, thus the dropdown box just keeps exceeding in width.

I have added this image to show what I mean: 
[image]

How do I stop this? I dont want to give it a fixed width because the list item just breaks free out of the dropdown box and goes on extending.

here is my code:

```css
body {
   padding-top: 102px;
   background-color: #4d4d4d;
   font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
 }
 .container {
   width: 1530px;
   margin-top: 0;
 }
 .navbar-fixed-top {
   background-color: #fff;
 }
 .navbar-header {
   min-height: 80px;
 }
 .hamburger-icon {
   margin-top: 20px;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
   line-height: 45px;
   font-size: 45px;
   color: #010101;
   text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-brand span {
   font-style: normal;
   color: #ff5500;
 }
 .search .input-group {
   padding-top: 15px;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 }
 .search .input-group input.search-field {
   border-radius: 0;
   border: 0;
   box-shadow: none;
   background-color: #fff;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: 100;
 }
 .search .input-group input.search-field:hover {
   background-color: transparent;
 }
 .search .input-group-btn button {
   padding: 2px;
   border: 0;
   box-shadow: none;
   background-color: transparent;
   border-radius: 0;
 }
 .search .input-group-btn button:hover {
   background-color: #f8f8f8;
   color: #ff5500;
 }
 .search .input-group-btn .glyphicon-search {
   font-size: 22px;
 }
 .dropdown-toggle.inbox {
   padding-top: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
 .dropdown-menu li {
   width: 400px;
 }
 .dropdown-menu.bell {
   background-color: #f8f8f8;
   border-radius: 0;
   box-shadow: 0;
 }
 .dropdown-menu.bell h4 {
   padding: 10px 0;
   color: #010101;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
 }
 .dropdown-menu.bell li a {
   padding-top: 5px;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
 }
 .nav>li.dropdown.bell>a:hover,
 .nav>li.dropdown.bell>a:focus {
   background-color: transparent;
 }
 .dropdown-menu.bell li.divider {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 20px;
 }
 .dropdown-menu.bell .label {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #ff5500;
   font-weight: 100;
 }
 .badge-notify {
   background: #ff5500;
   margin-top: -24px;
   margin-left: -20px;
   height: 1.7em;
 }
 /* caret for notification dropdown */
 .dropdown-menu.bell:before {
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right: 10%;
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 10px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   content: '';
 }
 .dropdown-menu.bell:after {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9px;
   right: 10%;
   display: inline-block;
   border-right: 9px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 9px solid #f8f8f8;
   border-left: 9px solid transparent;
   content: '';
 }
 .user span.fullname {
   font-size: 14px;
   color: #010101;
   font-weight: 400;
 }
 .user span:last-child {
   padding-right: 10px;
 }
 .user span:first-child {
   padding-right: 30px;
   padding-left: 10px;
 }
 .user .dropdown-menu.user-list {
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 0;
   border: 0;
   background-color: #f8f8f8
 }
 .user .dropdown-menu.user-list li a {
   margin: 5px 0px;
   color: #010101;
 }
 .user .dropdown-menu.user-list li a:hover {
   background-color: transparent;
   color: #ff5500;
 }
 .user .dropdown-menu.user-list li.divider {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 20px;
 }
 /* Large desktop */
 @media (max-width: 1590px) {
   .container {
     width: auto;
   }
 }
 /* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
 @media (max-width: 979px) {}
 /* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
   .container {
     width: auto;
   }
   .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
     font-size: 40px;
   }
   .dropdown.bell .inbox {
     width: 100% !important;
   }
   .dropdown-menu.bell h4 {
     margin: 0 0;
   }
   .dropdown-menu.bell:before,
   .dropdown-menu.bell:after {
     display: none;
   }
   .bell,
   .user {
     text-align: center;
   }
 }
 /* Landscape phones and down */
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
   .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
     font-size: 30px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-md" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hamburger-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BRAND<span>LOGO</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <!-- search bar -->
          <li class="dropdown search">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Search name or keyword" name="q">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/search-128.png" height="30" width="30" class=" avatar-img img-square">
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>

          <!-- notification bell -->
          <li class="dropdown bell">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle inbox" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-bell-outline-128.png" height="45" width="45" class=" avatar-img img-square">
              <span class="badge badge-notify">1</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu bell" role="menu">
              <li>
                <h4 class="menu-title">Notifications</h4>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-default">4:00 AM</span>Favourites Snippet</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">4:30 AM</span>Email marketing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">5:00 AM</span>Subscriber focused email blaaaa 
      blaaaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddblaaadddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
                            design</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="text-center">View All</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <!-- user login information -->
          <li class="dropdown user">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-128.png" height="50" width="50" ></span>
              <span class="fullname">Jacky Smith</span>
              <span><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png" height="20" width="20" ></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu user-list" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>dfsjfhskfs</p>


      <!-- <div class="chevron right">
     <a href="#"></a>
   </div>

   <div style="height: 1em;">
   </div> -->




    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Leo the lion I dont have the notifications functioning yet, I am just stating this is what I want it for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to give a fixed width, then you may use `max-width`. 
It will not set any fixed width but when the text will exceed the given `max-width`, it will automatically break down to a new line.

Comment: yeah, max-width sounds like the way to go. I might try the col-md-12 solution as well for the list items. Thanks, MeFaysal

Comment: Would you know how I could set my search box as well to fit nicely in responsive view? at the moment, a horizontal scrollbar displays because if it, and I dont like it...what do you think?

Comment: Most probably you will have to use some custom css in media query

Comment: Its in the snippet, you can check it out there when you decrease the browser in response view, the searchbar just doesnt sit comfortably with its width.

Comment: Alright, use media query when width less than 425px and decrease the width of the search bar to fit the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110538/discussion-between-mefaysal-and-krystyna).

Comment: .navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: to remove the horizontal bar. With an average query less than 767

Comment: exactly, you are also right.  Krystyna you may also try doing Naviego's solution in media query of width less than 767

Answer (score 1):

This works. You have to stick a DIV to all content and occupying 12 cells text, and do not overflow. In the text I have also gotten a span, texts can not go empty label, everything should always be labeled

```
<li>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="label label-warning">5:00 AM</span>
      <span>iber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla Subscriber focused email bla</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: it sure works! After some padding that span the text to edit the text and you're done! : D

Comment: remember to mark the correct answers with the "TICK" green. Because otherwise people will stop to help @Krystyna

Answer (score 0):

you should use a (max-width) for your div.

Comment: that sound not too bad of a solution, I will try that, thanks

Comment: in responsive view, my search box is not displaying properly with padding, because a horizontal scrollbar shows up, do you know how I can make the searchbox fit the width nicely??

Comment: @Krystyna  make sure of this
    '<html>
    <head>
        <link rel= "your bootstrap libraries" >
        <link rel="your css file" >'

the edited css file should be after the bootstrap

Comment: yes, I had that covered! :) my solution was this, I put white-space: normal; width: 350px; on my div and works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Property `white-space: normal` helps to wrap words on new line, when it necessary, but if you have too long words, property `word-break: break-word` helps you to break word on new line

```
.dropdown-menu.bell li a {

  ...

  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

[JSFiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/rp79Lmzr/)

Comment: hmm, this did not work in your jsFiddle example, its still doing the same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my solution working, with the help from the stackoverflow community!.

I included the following on my .dropdown-menu.bell > li > a:

```
     white-space: normal;
     width: 350px;
```